# It is about sending an email based on the changes in the sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I want my function to activate on specific sheet only. But I really do not know how to write. I have like 14 sheets. And anytime one of the sheets' values are changed. It automatically sends out an email which I do not want. I want my function to send email only based on the sheet I want. (I have add the trigger manually on my current project trigger).

```
function CheckbudgetAUD() {

  for(var i=2;i<1000; i++){
  var num1 = i;
  var r = 4;
  var department = "AUD";
  var transactionIDRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(department).getRange(num1,14);
  var transactionID = transactionIDRange.getValue();
  var monthRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(department).getRange(num1,12);
  var month = monthRange.getValue() ; 
  var costdescriptionRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(department).getRange(num1,3);
  var costdescription = costdescriptionRange.getValue();
  var costRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(department).getRange(num1,4);
  var cost = costRange.getValue();
  var actualbudgetRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(department).getRange(num1,4); 
  var actualbudget = actualbudgetRange.getValue();
  var ApprovalRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(department).getRange(num1,18);
  var Approval = ApprovalRange.getValue();
  var purposeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(department).getRange(num1,7);
  var purpose = purposeRange.getValue();
  var timeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(department).getRange(num1,1);
  var time = timeRange.getValue();
  var CEOsapprovalRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(department).getRange(num1,19);
  var CEOsapproval = CEOsapprovalRange.getValue();
  var addinformationRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(department).getRange(num1,5);
  var addi   = addinformationRange.getValue();
  var thisisdoneRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(department).getRange(num1,30);
  var thisisdone = thisisdoneRange.getValue();
  var BlankRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(department).getRange(num1,2);
  var Blank = BlankRange.getValue();

  //Emails Range
  var email1Range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Forecasted budget").getRange("F18");
  var email1address = email1Range.getValue();
  var email2Range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Forecasted budget").getRange("F21");
  var email2address = email2Range.getValue();
  var email3Range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(department).getRange(num1,6);
  var email3address = email3Range.getValue();

  // Messages Range
  var message1 = "Your request has been " + Approval + "d." + "\n" + "\n" + "Transaction ID: " + transactionID;    
  var message = "For the " + month + ", " + department + "'s " + costdescription + ' budget exceeded the limit'+ '\n'+ '\n'+ "CURRENT BUDGET APPLICATION INFORMATION" + "\n" + "COST: "+ cost + '\n' + "Transaction ID: "+ transactionID +'\n' + "Cost item: " + costdescription + "\n" + "Purpose: "+ purpose + "\n" + "Department Name: " + department + "\n" + "Timestamp: " + time + "\n" + "additional information: " +  addi+ "\n" + 'Click the link below to approve'+ '\n' + 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSduX3ol31Ddy3klEpynlO33wprEivAr-e9BL7fZ6Th-JQgjZA/viewform';     
  var subject = 'Exceeded the budget limit for current month';
  var subject1 = 'Form Approval/Decline';
   if ( Blank !== "" && thisisdone == "Apple"){
  MailApp.sendEmail(email3address, subject1, message1);        
    }

    //Over budget email
    if  ( Approval == "Decline" && thisisdone == "Apple"){
        if ( cost < 200000 ) {
            MailApp.sendEmail(email1address, subject, message);}
        else if ( cost >= 200000 ) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(email2address, subject, message);       
}
    }
  }
}
```

I am also basically sending out email to 3 different parties at the same time in one function. Just FYI.

Comment: What kind of trigger?

Comment: Ooops ...Either on Change or on Edit. I am not sure. But whenever the data entry happens. Simply put, I am linking that sheet with google form and whenever someone submit a form, they have to receive an email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might like to consider this sort of approach.  You will find it to run much faster.  Although there may be some  corrections you will want to make. I noticed some duplication in the range assignments which are reflected in  my assignments as well. Keep in mind that column number start at one and array indices start at zero.

```
function CheckbudgetAUD() {
  var department = "AUD";
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName(department)
  var fsh=ss.getSheetByName("Forcasted budget");
  var vA=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length; i++){
    var transactionID = vA[i][13];
    var month = vA[i][11]; 
    var costdescription = vA[i][2];
    var cost = vA[i][3];
    var actualbudget=vA[i][3];
    var Approval=vA[i][17];
    var purpose=vA[i][6];
    var time=vA[i][0];
    var CEOsapproval=vA[i][18];
    var addi=vA[i][4];
    var thisisdone=vA[i][29];
    var Blank=vA[i][1];
    var email1address = fsh.getRange("F18").getValue();
    var email2address = fsh.getRange("F21").getValue();
    var email3address = vA[i][5];
    var message1 = "Your request has been " + Approval + "d." + "\n" + "\n" + "Transaction ID: " + transactionID;    
    var message = "For the " + month + ", " + department + "'s " + costdescription + ' budget exceeded the limit'+ '\n'+ '\n'+ "CURRENT BUDGET APPLICATION INFORMATION" + "\n" + "COST: "+ cost + '\n' + "Transaction ID: "+ transactionID +'\n' + "Cost item: " + costdescription + "\n" + "Purpose: "+ purpose + "\n" + "Department Name: " + department + "\n" + "Timestamp: " + time + "\n" + "additional information: " +  addi+ "\n" + 'Click the link below to approve'+ '\n' + 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSduX3ol31Ddy3klEpynlO33wprEivAr-e9BL7fZ6Th-JQgjZA/viewform';     
    var subject = 'Exceeded the budget limit for current month';
    var subject1 = 'Form Approval/Decline';
    if (Blank!=="" && thisisdone=="Apple"){
      MailApp.sendEmail(email3address, subject1, message1);        
    }
    if  (Approval=="Decline" && thisisdone=="Apple"){
      if (cost<200000) {
        MailApp.sendEmail(email1address, subject, message);
      }else if( cost >= 200000 ) {
        MailApp.sendEmail(email2address, subject, message);       
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you're attempting to run something like this from onEdit() then you will want to limit which sheets that you want it to run on.  For example consider the event object to be represented by an e then

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='AUD')return;
```

This will limit the script to running only for sheet `AUD`.

Comment: Thank you for showing me the professional way. If I want to run something like onEdit(). Do I add the code function onEdit(e) after the previous function or before the previous function? 
Sorry if it is sound silly, I am just a beginner.

Comment: I copied+paste the onEdit(e) function  above the first function xD. Now it shows (Cannot call method "range" of undefined.). I am doing it something wrong for sure.

Comment: Well first of all it’s not a complete function. It’s just a starting portion and secondly I suspect you tried running it out of the script editor and you can’t do that you need to provide it an event object. I always run mine from athe onEdit trigger And just debug in place